# Angular formGroup how to detect if form trully changed in subscription?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to make a function which would detect if angular `formGroup` actually changed it's values :

```
 subscribeToFormChanges() {
    const formSub = this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(this.formGroup.getRawValue());
      console.log(value);
      if (this.formGroup.getRawValue() == value) {
        console.log('equal');
      } else {
        console.log('not changed');
      }
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => {
        this.subs.add(formSub);
      })
  }
```

WHY ? - because ther are selects where you can select the same value and it will `.setValue` on `control`.

But it always returns not changed even if i change values. **How to do it in the right way ?**

**Second approach :**

```
  subscribeToFormChanges() {
    const formSub = this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null), pairwise()).subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
      if (prev == next) {
        console.log('equal');
      } else {
        console.log('not changed');
      }
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => {
        this.subs.add(formSub);
      })
  }
```

**Returns not changed all the time**

Answer (score 0):

You're getting these results because the you're comparing 2 different references.

You could visualize the **form control tree** as follows:

```
// FG - FormGroup
// FC - FormControl

    FG
  /   \
 FC   FG
     /  \
   FC   FC <-- <select formControlName="yourSelect">
```

Whenever `FormControl.setValue` is invoked(e.g due to change coming from the user), all its ancestors will have to be updated. By `updated`, I mean updating the **user-interaction status**(`touched`, `pristine` etc), **invoking validators** and updating **validity status**.

The [`updateValueAndValidity`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L644-L666) method is responsible for such this. It's invoked by `FormControl.setValue`:

```js
this._setInitialStatus();
this._updateValue();

if (this.enabled) {
  this._cancelExistingSubscription();
  (this as { errors: ValidationErrors | null }).errors = this._runValidator();
  (this as { status: string }).status = this._calculateStatus();

  if (this.status === VALID || this.status === PENDING) {
    this._runAsyncValidator(opts.emitEvent);
  }
}

if (opts.emitEvent !== false) {
  (this.valueChanges as EventEmitter<any>).emit(this.value);
  (this.statusChanges as EventEmitter<string>).emit(this.status);
}

if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {
  this._parent.updateValueAndValidity(opts);
}
```

Note that this method is the same for: `FormControl`, `FormArray` and `FormGroup`.

As you can see, this is also the place where `this.valueChanges` emits. What this means is that the root node(e.g your `formGroup` in the example) will eventually be reached and you'll receive the **accumulated values** from all the other descendants(**form controls**).

The object you're interested in is assigned to `this.value` which is resolved in `this._updateValue()`, which is **entity-specific**. For the `FormGroup`, this is how the value is determined:

```js
_updateValue(): void {
    (this as {value: any}).value = this._reduceValue();
  }

_reduceValue() {
  return this._reduceChildren(
    {}, (acc: { [k: string]: AbstractControl }, control: AbstractControl, name: string) => {
      if (control.enabled || this.disabled) {
        acc[name] = control.value;
      }
      return acc;
    });
}
```

From the above you can notice `{}`, which is a new reference compared to the previous value object provided by `pairwise()`. So, this should explain why you're always getting that result.

One way to solve this is to perform a deep comparison between the previous and the current object values.

Another way would be to prevent the tree from being updated unless a new value comes in. This involves operating at `leaf` level(e.g `FormControl`s). You could create a **custom control-value-accessor** and do the logic there.

However, I don't think the `select` would emit a `change` event if the same value is selected. [Demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/irCFKdtVQQRUFrst8nes).

If you'd like to explore Angular Forms, I'd kindly recommend checking out [this article](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/).

Comment: I think it's too complicated

Comment: What do you find complicated?